# How can I simulate ffmpeg's empty_moov option within code?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Command-line ffmpeg has the ability to use an empty moov_atom at the beginning of a file.

More info:
http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-3

I would like to do the same thing, except within code.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is an `AVOption` for the mov muxer](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavformat/movenc.c;h=af7efc9ba127dade8918abc3092f4caec3e7630a;hb=HEAD#l52).

Things in avcodec, avformat, etc. can take `AVOption`s when setting them up. You can use [`av_opt_set`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__opt__set__funcs.html) to set these options. It would be something like:

```
// Prefixing it with '+' sets the flag
// Prefixing it with '-' unsets the flag
av_opt_set(formatContext, "movflags", "+empty_moov", 0);
```